# позиция причастного оборота

Tags: причастия, причастный-оборот

Объясните, пожалуйста, есть ли ошибка в предложении: *Расходы на возмещение затрат государственным унитарным предприятиям, возникших в результате падения объемов грузооборота*.

Отмечу, что согласование причастия приведено корректное, оно зависит от слова "затрат". А вопрос в том, существует ли **запрет на такой вот разрыв причастия и определяемого слова**. Меня не интересуют рекомендации, стилистика, а именно правило русского языка, которое такой разрыв **запрещает**.

Буду очень благодарен ответам!

Comment: Дело в том, что это как раз по части стилистики. Грамматической ошибки в этом нет.

Answer (score 1):

В спорах о русском языке люди очень любят использовать, как им кажется, убийственный прием: "Где написано что так нельзя? Покажите правило!"

На самом деле это демонстрирует, что человек не очень знаком с тем, как устроен язык и науки, его изучающие. Во-первых, разнообразие и гибкость языка не позволяют описать все возможные сочетания слов, синтаксические конструкции и тонкости грамматики. Во-вторых, язык быстро меняется, и то, что вчера было правилом, сегодня может оказаться устаревшим.

Отвечая на ваш вопрос: **такого правила вы не найдете, потому что его нет**. Но предложение стилистически некорректно. Определяемое слово не только стоит достаточно далеко от причастного оборота, но и само по себе разбивает синтагму *возмещение предприятиям*. Таким образом получается, что две синтагмы по очереди "перебивают" друг друга.

Сравните с вашей фразой вот такую, например:
*Возмещение **затрат предпринимателя**, возникших в результате падения объемов грузооборота*.

А теперь вот такую:
***Возмещение** затрат **предпринимателю**, возникших в результате падения объемов грузооборота*.

В первой все в порядке. Во второй – нет.

Comment: Интересные примеры в конце.

Comment: Про синтагмы не очень понятно. Оно ведь не разбивает, "возмещение предприятиям", наоборот, остаётся неразделённым. И что кого перебивает... Лучше подробнее расписать это всё.

Comment: Я боюсь не очень верно выразить мысль с точки зрения лингвистической терминологии. _Возмещение_ не требует дополнения в дательном падеже (возмещение _кому?_),  факультативно. А вот прямое дополнение необходимо: возмещение _чего?_. И здесь основная конструкция - это "возмещение затрат", а не "возмещение предприятиям". Поэтому если не учитывать причастный оборот, фраза "возмещение затрат предприятиям" звучит лучше, чем "возмещение предприятиям затрат". Но "затраты" в свою очередь составляют цельную конструкцию с определением - "возникших". Таким образом две синтагмы взаимно разбивают друг друга.

Comment: Это да, хотя изредка "возмещение" и без "чего?" (в Нацкорпусе). *Таким образом получается, что две синтагмы по очереди "перебивают" друг друга* — там лучше указать, какие именно. Так вы хотите перенести "затрат" к причастному обороту... А мне хочется, чтобы "разбивало синтагму" так: *Расходы на возмещение затрат, возникших в результате падения объемов грузооборота, государственным унитарным предприятиям.* Такая структура удачна для делового стиля.

Comment: Мы так до валентностей договоримся :) Ваш пример для делового стиля подходит, грамматически он корректен, стилистически - приемлем. И в нем как раз не разбиваются крепкие связи: _возмещение затрат_, _затрат, возникших_.

Comment: Понимаю, что сама себе немного противоречу в объяснениях. Подумаю, как переформулировать ответ.

Comment: Не помешает расписать в том абзаце, а то закручено и мало, чтобы понять мысль. А противоречия что-то и не заметил.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение! Вы говорите, что это из области стилистики, а сами приводите доказательства с грамматической точки зрения. Но дело в том, что это предложение приведено из классификации расходов бюджета субъекта РФ. Заменить окончание, как вы предлагаете, невозможно, это повлияет на практику правоприменения. При окончании в родительном падеже исполнитель упрется в то, что не написано, КОМУ возмещаем затраты. Определение в родительном падеже его не убедит. Так что теперь остается рассуждать, какой смысловой компонент главнее: КОМУ или ЧТО? В данном предложении на первом месте стоит ЧТО.

Comment: к слову о познаниях русского языка...так мы сюда и обращаемся, чтобы знатоки просветили. имеем дело с людьми, которые действуют строго по инструкции. там установка "нет правила = нет нарушения", уж поймите. не все такие высокие грамотеи, как вы. особенно люди, которые днями-ночами сидят в цифрах.